# Is it practically possible to reuse oracle database files (.dbf) in other docker containers

Tags: oracle, docker

I have an oracle 12 running docker container, lets say **ora_db1** where some initial sql scripts and import of a dump file were executed. As the import takes quite a while, therefore i would like to reuse the existing .dbf files stored in the path **/opt/oracle/oradata** of container **ora_db1** for some other containers, lets say **ora_db2** and **ora_db3**

So far i tried to use docker volume when starting the container **ora_db1**, something like

```
docker run --name ora_db1 -p <port>:<port> -v C:\host\path:/opt/oracle/oradata xyz_image:v1
```

After that, i copy data from C:\host\path to C:\host\path2 and start another container

```
docker run --name ora_db2 -p <port>:<port> -v C:\host\path2:/opt/oracle/oradata xyz_image:v1
```

just to shadow all the .dbf files stored in C:\host\path2 to /opt/oracle/oradata. But unfortunately, i see an error

```
SQL> ORA-01261: Parameter db_recovery_file_dest destination string cannot be translated
ORA-01262: Stat failed on a file destination directory
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
SQL> Disconnected
#####################################
########### E R R O R ###############
DATABASE SETUP WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!
Please check output for further info!
########### E R R O R ###############
#####################################
```

Comment: That error sounds like your `db_recovery_file_dest` parameter on ora_db2 points to a directory that can't be read. It's unrelated to the DBFs. Yes, you can copy DBFs to a different database, e.g.: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119283/import-database-from-oracle-dbf-files

Comment: You might be looking for the feature called transportable tablespaces. I haven't used it myself, but I think the general idea is that you can copy the files associated with tablespaces - although you'll also need to run a few commands to prepare for the export and import of the files.

Comment: @JonHeller can you refer me to any specific link ? thanks

Comment: @john.michael Try [this page on oracle-base.com](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/transportable-tablespaces). I haven't used that page myself, but that site is usually pretty good.